# Call to undefined function

Tags: nodes

After creating the node (from a default and custom node) I received the following error,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function creative_customize_comment_form()
  in /home/MYSITE/public_html/includes/form.inc on line 1865
```

this happens for all users even admin.

Comment: "from a default and custom node" => could you explain this more?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `creative_customize_comment_form()` is a custom form function, so it probably exists in either:

1. A file inside a module that's not enabled, so Drupal can't find it
2. An include file in the module that's not automagically included during the page build.

The solution to the first is obviously to enable the module.

The solution to the second is to Make sure the appropriate file is included in the page build, using `module_load_include()`, e.g.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'creative_customize', 'creative_customize.pages');
// Now call drupal_get_form()...
```

Without more information I can't think of any other reason (other than the function name itself being incorrect) that `drupal_get_form()` would fail.

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7

Comment: "from a default and custom" Meaning from A Basic Page or an Article. As well as a custom content type I added.

I'm trying to think of what module might yield that error but Im not sure.

Comment: I believe creative is referring to the theme I am using. My recent error log for the site is showing the "file not found error" with the message favicon.ico

Comment: fixing Favicon error did not resolve the issue.

Comment: The favicon thing in Apache's error log is just a 404 warning, it won't fix a PHP issue. Try to find a function called `creative_customize_comment_form` in your theme, and see what file it's in. Then make sure that file is included in the appropriate page build and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for your help, even if I found where the that function is in my field. Would i use the code above? Im not the best when it comes to creating custom anything. Im heavily reliant on modules to do the work for me. Thanks again

Comment: If it's in a theme then you won't need `module_load_include()`...best thing you can do is find out where the function is, and if you can't work out why it doesn't work from there edit your question with some more info. That'll get it pushed to the top of the list on the main page and get some more eyes on it :)

Comment: I searched the form.inc for "creative" and found nothing.
and line 1865 is " $element = $function($element, $form_state);"

Comment: I Switched themes, i can live wit =h that. issue resolved.